# Need assist with button gets input from drop down for redirect

Tags: javascript

Hello:  I am trying to do something relatively simple I think, but I am fumbling around trying to figure this out and have gotten nowhere.  Essentially all I want is this:

1. have a drop down on a page with a few options with a submit button below the drop down;
2. if you select different items in the drop down it will basically redirect you to different locations based on what you chose… trying to do this with javascript...
3. I have tried this a number of ways using "on click' "get element by id" and so on but cannot get anything to work.
4. my latest attempt I thought I would try to use "on change" on the drop down; but that did not help either

here is my code:

```
<form>
<select id="user1" name="user1" onchange="gfunction1(this)">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="coach_input">Submit a Score</option>
<option value="team_pages">Get Team Information</option>
</select>

<div style="text-align: center;">

<button onclick="gfunction2()">Submit</button>

</div>

</form>

<script>
var gc_user2;

function g_function1(sel) {
 var value = sel.value;  
 gc_user2 = value;
 }



function gfunction2() {


if (gc_user2 === "coach_input")
{
window.location=”http://blastr.com”;
}

else if (gc_user2 === "team_pages")
{
 window.location=”http://google.com”;
}
</script>
```

I am wondering if anyone can help with this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. It works using **document.getElementById**. It simply **changes** the **action attribute** of the form i.e, where to send the form inputs, **based on what you select**.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirect Sample</title>
    <script>

    function g_function1() {
        var dropdown1 = document.getElementById("user1");

            if (dropdown1.selectedIndex === 1) {
                document.getElementById("frm").action="http://blastr.com";
            }
            else if (dropdown1.selectedIndex === 2) {
                document.getElementById("frm").action="http://google.com";
            }
     }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="" id="frm" method="get">
   <select id="user1" name="user1" onchange="g_function1()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="coach_input">Submit a Score</option>
        <option value="team_pages">Get Team Information</option>
   </select>

   <div style="text-align: center;">

        <button>Submit</button>

   </div>

   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The **onChange** event on the select tag calls the function **g_function1**().
It changes the action attribute based on the index of the option selected.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jquery for this and use this event: (not tested, but you get the idea)

```
$('user1').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    if (valueSelected === "coach_input")
   {
     window.location=”http://blastr.com”;
   }

   else if (valueSelected  === "team_pages")
   {
      window.location=”http://google.com”;
   }
});
```